# Configure IIS server to work with Aurelia framework and push state

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-web-api, pushstate, aurelia

I have created a basic aurelia app starting from [this repo](https://github.com/cmichaelgraham/aurelia-typescript/tree/master/aurelia-vs-ts) and I was trying to get rid of the # (hashtag) in the URL bar.

I have 2 projects, one running WebApi on a machine and one running an empty web project (not MVC) on another machine. On the [official documentation website](http://aurelia.io/docs.html#configuring-push-state) it only says how to configure your routes but my project is not MVC oriented.

How can I configure the IIS server from Web.config in a sense that when I access `http://localhost/home` it should start the aurelia framework rather than the 404 not found page?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

I'm using the Azure which needed a web.config to handle non hash routing correctly, it just redirects all routes into the index.html which contains the aurelia app. Without it (or a similar technique) it was giving 404s.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<configuration>
    <system.webServer>
     <rewrite>
             <rules>
                 <remove name="redirect all requests" />
                 <rule name="redirect all requests" stopProcessing="true">
                     <match url="^(.*)$" ignoreCase="false" />
                     <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAll">
                         <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsFile" negate="true" pattern="" ignoreCase="false" />
                     </conditions>
                     <action type="Rewrite" url="index.html" appendQueryString="true" />
                 </rule>
             </rules>
         </rewrite>
    </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thank you. I ended up using something similar :)

Comment: Hey Matt, where do you put this `web.config`? I've added mine inside de `wwwroot` folder but I still get 404's

Comment: @SergiPapaseit that's exactly where I put it, the only time I got 404s was with a type of file that azure doesn't handle by default, like woff or json files.

Comment: Tip: you need to have the [IIS URL Rewrite extension](https://www.iis.net/downloads/microsoft/url-rewrite) installed on your Windows server for this to take effect.