# IIS push state thinks all my react routes are static files

Tags: iis, reactjs, react-router, pushstate

Im trying to set up my IIS to support push state by following these two posts. [Configure IIS server to work with Aurelia framework and push state](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32114794/configure-iis-server-to-work-with-aurelia-framework-and-push-state)

https://gist.github.com/jdmonty/8e579b3b7c19ad80b78a

However every time I try to visit a route like localhost/app/myroute IIS thinks `myroute` is a static file and IIS returns a 404 with

```
Module  IIS Web Core
Notification    MapRequestHandler
Handler StaticFile
```

I found in my sites Handler Mappings theres a Static File Handler with a rule of `*` which I guess is handling my request because it has no extension. I tried removing the rule and tried editing the rule to `*.*` to force an extension but neither seemed to work. Here is my current web config rewrite rules

```
<rule name="Main Rule" stopProcessing="true">
      <match url=".*" />
      <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAll">
           <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsFile" negate="true" />
           <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsDirectory" negate="true" />
           <add input="api.*" negate="true" />
       </conditions>
       <action type="Rewrite" url="/app/" />
 </rule>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this using a combination of `useBaseName` in react router and `<base href="/app">` in my index.html file.

Seemed what was happening was all the static resources in my index.html were the issue without `<base href>` set which was causing the rule to trigger and not give me the correct resource back.