# Direct URL works locally but not on server

Tags: aurelia

I have a project created using Aurelia CLI v0.33.1 using Webpack. I have enabled pushState and index.ejs contains a `<head>` with:

```
<base href="<%- htmlWebpackPlugin.options.metadata.baseUrl %>">
```

which is currently set to "/" in my webpack.config.js (as I've seen suggested elsewhere for similar issues).

When I access the url locally via, `http://localhost:8080/orders`, I can view the page. After publishing to an Azure host, accessing `https://<AzureHostURL>/orders` results in a 404.

If I navigate to `https://<AzureHostURL>` and use the UI to navigate to `/orders` it works as expected.

It is unclear to me what the cause of this issue could be.

Comment: check out [this article](http://manuelguilbault.com/blog/2017/08/22/Hosting-an-Aurelia-app-on-Azure/) right about the middle, it explaines about push state with azure

Comment: Thanks @avrahamcool! That led me in the right direction!

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to direction from @avrahamcool, which provided me with an understanding of the problem, I found [this Stack Overflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32114794/configure-iis-server-to-work-with-aurelia-framework-and-push-state) which provided the exact solution I needed.